# TableLayoutPanel does not show up C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I want to create a tablelayoutpanel programmatically. I have code as follows:

```
        TableLayoutPanel tlpCurrent = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Clear();
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));
        tlpCurrent.RowCount++;
        tlpCurrent.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 40f));

        tlpCurrent.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        tlpCurrent.ColumnCount++;
        tlpCurrent.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150f));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            tlpCurrent.ColumnCount++;
            tlpCurrent.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150f));
        }

        tlpCurrent.Location = new Point(500, 100);
        tlpCurrent.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
        tlpCurrent.AutoSize = true;
        this.Controls.Add(tlpCurrent);
```

But I cannot see it on windows form. I am sure this code runs without any error. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect to see if you don't add any content to the panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the borders visible, you can use:

```
tlpCurrent.CellBorderStyle= TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
```